# Monotouch set status bar Hidden - API change secure

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How can I hide the status bar in a Monotouch application in such a way that it is backwards compatible on iOS 3.X while developing on iOS >= 4.X?

Comment: -1 this isn't a question. It's just a poor attempt at rep boosting - ripped off from http://blog.touch4apps.com/home/iphone-monotouch-development/monotouch-set-status-bar-hidden (I'm aware its your blog, but still).

Comment: StackOverflow encourages people to post questions with an answer when they just found a solution to a problem.   It is standard practice around here.

Comment: my bad - I guess it was just the cynic in me coming out

Answer (score 5):

If you ever needed to set the status bar hidden in Monotouch App, and wanted to do it properly for code that runs backward compatible on OS 3.X while developing on iOS SDK 4.X and also for newer devices, here is the answer:

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:")))
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(true, UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade);
else
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(true, true);
```